# How to use seleniumRC in Junit framework on dynamically changing elementids

Tags: css, selenium, element, xpath

I am trying to automate a work flow process .In this,I need to click on a link positioned in any of the rows of table.Thing is all links available in all rows have same element ID and in the source code I have a java script like " ("Element ID" @ Onclick..***java script*******:).....SO here after clicking it is connecting  one form to another form by inputting some value in java script code and also one value in java script dynamically changes.How do I click on that link now?Is there any solution using xpath or so...to exactly click on that link based on CSS classID or so...Please help me out..Main problem is...all links in rows have same element ID and dynamically changing java script .
I am trying to use selenium.focus() and selenium.clickAndwait().But these are helpless.as it is not able to identify link ID only.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Provide reduce input sample if you need an XPath expression selecting the nodes you want.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be with xpath.

Something like `//*[@onclick='javascript']` will work but this can make the tests extremely flaky because if the inline javascript changes or if its removed in preference of addEventListener to the element.

something like `//*[@class='cssClass']` will work. I think that you will need to speak to the developers and ask them to help make it more testable.